# JQuery UI autocomplete change event - resetting selection ID

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using the AutoComplete UI widget for a form to allow users to type in a customer name.  The idea is that they can either select an existing customer and populate other fields in the form, or they can free-type a new customer to be created.  When a user selects an existing customer, I use the `select` event to populate a hidden input to store the ID associated with that customer.

The problem I'm having is if a user first selects a customer from the list but then goes in and edits the text, in effect creating a new customer, I need to be able to clear out that hidden input ID value.

I referred to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820338/jquery-ui-autocomplete-event-change) and created the following code:

```
$(function() {
            $("#customerName").autocomplete({
                source: "/Customers/CustomerListJSON",
                minLength: 2,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    $("#customerId").val(ui.item ? ui.item.Id : "");
                },
                change: function(event, ui) {
                    try {
                        $("#trace").append(document.createTextNode(event.originalEvent.type + ", "));
                        if (event.originalEvent.type != "menuselected")
                            $("#customerId").val("");
                    } catch (err) {
                        $("#customerId").val("");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

The problem is that the change event is fired on `blur`, so if a user selects a customer, the hidden input value is populated, but as soon as they move focus off the input box it's cleared right away.  However, if I exclude the `blur` event from the `event.originalEvent.type` test, then the hidden field's value never gets reset in the original scenario where a user edits a previously-selected value.

Has anyone had to tackle this before, and if so can you offer some guidance on how I can manage that hidden input's value so it's populated *only* when an item is selected from the list and cleared with any other value?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Looks like I solved this pretty quickly on my own.  Referring to the [JQuery UI wiki](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/Autocomplete), the `ui` item in the `change` event is the same one in the `select` event, so I can modify my code to read like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#customerName").autocomplete({
        source: "/Customers/CustomerListJSON",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $("#customerOrganizationId").val(ui.item ? ui.item.Id : "");
        },
        change: function(event, ui) {
            $("#customerOrganizationId").val(ui.item ? ui.item.Id : "");
        }
    });
});
```

There's no need to test for the event, just for whether there is an item in the `ui` argument.  The ID setting in the `select` event is probably redundant, but to be safe I'm going to keep both.

Comment: Cool! I have the same need but now I need multiple autocomplete, so for example if I select `customer1` his id would be set in the hidden field now I type `abcd` now again I trigger the autocomplete and I select `customer2` so his id should be pushed, now if I remove `customer2` only his id should be removed from hidden list, any quick thoughts ?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for something like the tagging tools. The autocomplete tool will do this, but it's not pretty. I prefer something like this: http://webspirited.com/tagit/#demos. There are a few controls like this out there...Tagit is just one I've used in the past with success.

Comment: It helps but there should be content too, so if I use trigger string it should trigger the auto-complete not otherwise

Comment: @Josh I'm facing a strange issue with that scenario.
When the user type any letter I want that the change event will be fire , it actually fire but only when I open the rendered html using Firebug/chrome debugger.
I'm mean If I'm not using the firebug -> the change event is not fire at all.I'm using the same code as yours. have any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: No, sorry. That sounds like a browser issue. I'd suggest testing on another browser.

Comment: This is a good solution @Josh! I have a similar task that goes one step further - taking care of "smart resp. critical users". :) Maybe you are interested in the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23778628/firing-event-on-jquery-ui-autocomplete-before-minlength

Comment: are you using **devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete**  because it's not working in this. @Josh

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
$("#customerName").autocomplete({
    source: "/Customers/CustomerListJSON",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $("#customerId").val(ui.item ? ui.item.Id : "");
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        try {
            $("#trace").append(document.createTextNode(event.originalEvent.type + ", "));
            if (event.originalEvent.type != "menuselected")
                $("#customerId").val("");
        } catch (err) {
            $("#customerId").val("");
        }
    }
});
});
```