# Select first if return key is pressed and there isn't item selected with jquery ui autocomplete

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

i'm using jquery ui autocomplete. 
I want that when there isn't items selected and user press return key, the first element of the results is selected automatically.

is possible do it?

How can i do?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this solution:

https://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions/blob/master/autocomplete/jquery.ui.autocomplete.selectFirst.js

Answer (score 0):

Use the **change** event, and test whether there was an item selected.

```
,change: function(event,ui) {
    // the user has tabbed away without choosing anything from the list
    // console.log(ui.item);    
    if( ui.item == null ) {
        console.log("no item selected")
    }
}
```

here's that event in documentation for jQueryUI 1.8.6 http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-change

and here's another stackoverflow question with a much more complicated solution, along the same lines: [Jquery UI autocomplete event change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820338/jquery-ui-autocomplete-event-change)